# How can I make my iPhone application available to some specific customers?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I'm new to apple development. Following is the client requirement:
1. App should be free to customer.
2. Only authorized customers can download the app.
3. Customers should also receive notifications on app updates.

I searched the internet then found two solutions.
1. Developer Enterprise Program
2. Custom B2B apps

First I tried for Enterprise Program: Apple allow this program only for employees within the organization.

Then I intended to use Custom B2B apps using Developer account. For this, Apple claims that "You can offer custom apps for free or at any price tier you select" at [this link](https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/).
But when I tried to upload the app while selecting the Custom B2B app check box with Free Tier selected and clicked continue it gave me following error "For a custom B2B app, you must select Price Tier 10 or higher"

Now I'm stuck, Am I missing something? If it is not a correct solution then which solution I should suggest to client and my CEO because both are annoyed. Please help me.

Comment: Contact Apple's support and ask them why it's not letting you give it for free.

Comment: According to apple own B2B website - https://developer.apple.com/programs/volume/b2b/ - "You can offer custom apps for free or at any price tier you select. Once you identify your customers and release date, you’re all set". Call their support if you cannot make it free. You should select whatever price you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this response from Apple Support, apparently you need to accept the payment contract beforehand:

> Regarding the issue saving, you are correct B2B apps can be free,
>   however, even though custom B2B apps may be free you must have a Paid
>   Applications contract for your app to be visible on the Custom B2B App
>   Store.
>
> You can request this contract and complete all setup options in iTunes
>   Connect by visiting your "Agreements, Tax, and Banking”. Once you have
>   done this try editing the app once again to enable for B2B.

Answer (score -2):

1. App should be free to customer.
   answer: You can upload it with any developer account, maybe a personal or a company, developer account. Users will only use it if they have an account for the app.
2. Only authorized customers can download the app.
   answer: Have a backend service where you can send a user and password  to that users. Something related on what the banks do, they have the apps but you can't create a acccount, you will need your users to request the account for your app.
3. Customers should also receive notifications on app updates.
   answer: Depending on your amount of expected users I would suggest Parse.com as a backend service so you can send push notifications otherwise build your own backend service, probably doing it using Nodejs or Ruby on rails with Heroku could be your best option.

Hope this helps you clarify.

Comment: If apple is providing b2b solution then why should I go for custom solution

Comment: The problem is that if you do #2, apple may reject the app; because is not open to all users.